# Java: How to start multi forever server in one shell?

Tags: java, shell

Let's say `Server.class` will listen to some port forever, and I can pass argument to specify the port. For instance,

```
java Server 4444
```

Now I would like to start multi server in one shell script.

Is it possible?

Comment: You mean like run multiple instances of `Server` each listening to a different port? Of course that should be doable just look for how to use loops in shell scripts.

Comment: On any kind of Unix, you can append & to a command line command; then that command is started as background job. But besides: that is not really a java question - as you are basically asking "how can start any program in parallel" in a shell. It doesn't really matter whether that program is java; or anything else. In other words: you really want to study the capabilities of your operating system to a certain degree. You have to understand the environment you are operating in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can start a process in the background with `&` and you can set the process to ignore the hup  (hangup) signal with `nohup`. Something like,

```
nohup java Server 3333 &
nohup java Server 4444 &
```